# Split email input & registration link from password controls in Azure B2C custom policy login

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I've been going through the Azure AD B2C samples and have put together something that uses home realm discovery:
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/home-realm-discovery-modern

I therefore currently have two screens where on screen one I have an email input and on screen two I have a standard login form (email, password, forgot link, register link). I'd now like to expand on top of this to create a similar flow to one that Microsoft uses to split the email input and register link on the login form from the password input and forgot password link:

[image]

- Screen 1: Enter email address or choose a generic provider (Azure AD,
  facebook, twitter etc)
- Screen 2: If email address is known, the user
  will be redirected to their provider using home realm discovery,
  otherwise they will enter their password.

The thing I'm having trouble with is splitting the password box from the registration link. On screen 1, I'd like to display an email input and a registration link, and on screen two I'd like to have the password input.

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/self-asserted-technical-profile#metadata), the SignUpTarget can be enabled/disabled, but only using the unifiedssp or unifiedssd uris. When I choose this for the first screen however, the password input is *always* added. Is there a simple solution to this?

I'd like to have

- Screen 1: Email input, registration link, **no** password input (plus
  additional claim providers)
- Screen 2: Password input, forgot password link, **no** registration link

Thanks for any assistance!